# Problem with loading .sh files call out by /usr/bin/php

Tags: linux, php, bash, scripting

When my web site is calling out a bash script with /usr/bin/php i'm geting this error

Failed loading /projects/common/zend/lib/ZendOptimizer.so: /projects/common/zend/lib/ZendOptimizer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

the file /projects/common/zend/lib/ZendOptimizer.so is there where it should be i dont know how to resolve this

Comment: Do you get the same error when running `php -v`?

Comment: php -v shows this
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/lib/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: undefined symbol: gc_remove_zval_from_buffer
PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Nov 29 2010 16:47:37) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layer 8 error: one of the programers moved the file from orginal location..

Answer (score 0):

> the file /projects/common/zend/lib/ZendOptimizer.so is there

And is it readable by the uid PHP is running as? Is the PHP running chroot?

Comment: php is not chrooted .... and the problem was solved .... one of programers moved the file from orginal location.... god how i hate situations like this  ;)

Comment: @B14D3: if the problem was solved, can you either answer the question yourself or close it?